# How to send data from a Python asyncio socket server to a subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio, coroutine

Python 3.6

This program:

1. launches ffmpeg as a subprocess
2. waits for a socket connection
3. receives PNG images on the socket
4. sends the PNG images to ffmpeg
   stdin

The problem is step 4.  I can't work out how to send the received PNG image from the coroutine to the stdin of the ffmpeg subprocess. Can anyone please point me in the right direction to send the PNG image to the stdin of the ffmpeg subprocess?

EDIT: to clarify - there's nothing wrong with this code, it receives the PNGs fine over the socket.  I just don't have any idea how to send the PNGs on into the stdin of ffmpeg.  I've done quite alot of Python but asyncio is new to me and how things tie together is a mystery.

thanks!

```
import asyncio
import argparse, sys
import sys
import base64
from struct import unpack

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--port', help='ffmpeg listen port')
parser.add_argument('--outputfilename', help='ffmpeg output filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.port:
    print("port is required")
    sys.exit(1)
if not args.outputfilename:
    print("outputfilename is required")
    sys.exit(1)

async def _read_stream(stream, cb):
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if line:
            cb(line)
        else:
            break

async def _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    await asyncio.wait([
        _read_stream(process.stdout, stdout_cb),
        _read_stream(process.stderr, stderr_cb)
    ])
    return await process.wait()


def process_stderr(line):
    # ffmpeg finishes processing and writes the output file when its input is closed
    # thus the completion message will come out of stderr only when the socket or stdin or whatever is closed
    line = line.decode()
    print(line)
    if "Output" in line:
        if args.outputfilename in line:
            print('finished!!!!')
            sys.exit(0)

def process_stdout(line):
    print("STDOUT: %s" % line)

def spawn_ffmpeg(listenport, outputfilename, framerate=30, format='webm'):
    outputdirectory = "sftp://username:password@10.0.0.196/var/www/static/"
    input_type = "pipe:0" #stdin

    params = \
        f"ffmpeg  " \
        f"-loglevel 56 " \
        f"-y -framerate {framerate} " \
        f"-f image2pipe " \
        f"-i {input_type} " \
        f"-c:v libvpx-vp9 " \
        f"-b:v 1024k " \
        f"-q:v 0 " \
        f"-pix_fmt yuva420p " \
        f"{outputdirectory}{outputfilename} "

    return params


async def socket_png_receiver(reader, writer):
    while True:
        # first the client sends the length of the data to us
        lengthbuf = await reader.read(4)
        length, = unpack('!I', lengthbuf)
        if length == 0:
            print("length was 0, finish") # a zero length PNG says that there are no more frames
            break
        # then we read the PNG
        data = await reader.read(length)
        data = data.decode() # from bytes to string
        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(data) # from base64 to bytes
        # next line was just a guess, so I have commented it out.
        #await proc.communicate(png_bytes)
        print("Got PNG, length", length)
    return


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
command = spawn_ffmpeg("24897", args.outputfilename)
ffmpeg_process = _stream_subprocess(
    command.split(),
    process_stdout,
    process_stderr,
)
#coro = asyncio.start_server(socket_png_receiver, '0.0.0.0', args.port, ffmpeg_process, loop=loop)
coro = asyncio.start_server(socket_png_receiver, '0.0.0.0', args.port, loop=loop)
several_futures = asyncio.gather(ffmpeg_process, coro)
server = loop.run_until_complete(several_futures)
server.close()
loop.close()
```

Here are the changes suggested by @user4815162342

```
import asyncio
import argparse, sys
import sys
import base64
from struct import unpack

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--port', help='ffmpeg listen port')
parser.add_argument('--outputfilename', help='ffmpeg output filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
if not args.port:
    print("port is required")
    sys.exit(1)
if not args.outputfilename:
    print("outputfilename is required")
    sys.exit(1)
if not args.outputfilename.endswith('.webm'):
    print("outputfilename must end with '.webm'")
    sys.exit(1)

async def _read_stream(stream, cb):
    while True:
        line = await stream.readline()
        if line:
            cb(line)
        else:
            break


async def _stream_subprocess(cmd, stdout_cb, stderr_cb):
    global process
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *cmd,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    await asyncio.wait([
        _read_stream(process.stdout, stdout_cb),
        _read_stream(process.stderr, stderr_cb)
    ])
    return await process.wait()


def process_stderr(line):
    # ffmpeg finishes processing and writes the output file when its input is closed
    # thus the completion message will come out of stderr only when the socket or stdin or whatever is closed
    line = line.decode()
    print(line)
    if "Output" in line:
        if args.outputfilename in line:
            print('finished!!!!')
            sys.exit(0)


def process_stdout(line):
    print("STDOUT: %s" % line)


def spawn_ffmpeg(listenport, outputfilename, framerate=30, format='webm'):
    outputdirectory = "sftp://username:password@10.0.0.196/var/www/static/"
    input_type = "pipe:0"  # stdin

    params = \
        f"ffmpeg  " \
        f"-loglevel 56 " \
        f"-y " \
        f"-framerate {framerate} " \
        f"-i {input_type} " \
        f"{outputdirectory}{outputfilename} "

    print(params)
    return params


async def socket_png_receiver(reader, writer):
    while True:
        # first the client sends the length of the data to us
        lengthbuf = await reader.readexactly(4)
        length, = unpack('!I', lengthbuf)
        if length == 0:
            print("length was 0, finish")  # a zero length PNG says that there are no more frames
            break
        # then we read the PNG
        print("Got PNG, length", length)
        data = await reader.readexactly(length)
        print(data)
        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(data)  # from base64 to bytes
        process.stdin.write(png_bytes)
    return


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
command = spawn_ffmpeg("24897", args.outputfilename)
ffmpeg_process = _stream_subprocess(
    command.split(),
    process_stdout,
    process_stderr,
)
coro = asyncio.start_server(socket_png_receiver, '0.0.0.0', args.port, loop=loop)
several_futures = asyncio.gather(ffmpeg_process, coro)
server = loop.run_until_complete(several_futures)
server.close()
loop.close()
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify what exactly goes wrong with the provided implementation, but perhaps you should try to send the data using: `proc.stdin.write(png_bytes)` followed by `proc.stdin.close()`?

Comment: Also, `await reader.read(length)` should really be `await reader.readexactly(length)`. The argument to [`StreamReader.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read) is the _maximum_, not exact number of bytes to read.

Comment: Another suspect thing is that `socket_png_receiver` appears to expect that it would keep sending data to *the same* ffmpeg process. That means that ffmpeg must be able to process multiple chunks of data on its stdin, i.e. that it needs to have a delimiting protocol like you implement by packing the length before the data. I suspect that you should instead start a new ffmpeg process in each iteration of the loop in `socket_png_receiver`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I've updated the code - there was an error in the line starting coro, so I have corrected it and left the old line commented out. I have also commented out await proc.communicate(png_bytes) because it was nothing more than a voodoo guess as to how to achieve my goal and just caused an error.  So, the code actually works fine, except there's just no mechanism for sending data to the ffmpeg stdin because I just can't figure out how at all.

Comment: @user4815162342 you are correct - socket_png_receiver will send ONLY to the one ffmpeg process. The idea is that once the sequence of PNG images is finished then both ffmpeg and this program that wraps it will exit.

Comment: My other remarks still apply, though. Another one: why are you calling `decode()` to "convert bytes to string"? A PNG buffer is not a Unicode string.

Comment: @user4815162342 The PNG actually arrives over the socket in base64.

Comment: ffmpeg does actually handle a continuous stream of PNG images pumped into it (as bytes, not base64), which it converts into whatever the output format is.  ffmpeg doesn't seem to need any delimiter between the PNG images.  I've done that quite alot - seems to work fine.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks - good pickup regarding await reader.readexactly(length)

Comment: In that case, `proc.stdin.write(png_bytes)` sounds like exactly what you need (in addition to the change to `readexactly` which you've already implemented).

Comment: Also, note that you still don't need to decode base64 bytes to a base64 string - `base64.b64decode` appears quite capable of transforming bytes to bytes: `base64.b64decode(b'foo=') -> b'~\x8a'`

Comment: @user4815162342 I don't have my head around scope within asyncio - I'm not even sure yet if scope is any different - but as it stands, proc is out of scope in that callback - can you suggest what "the right way" is for me to get it into socket_png_receiver so I can execute it?

Comment: `proc.communicate()` is in this case the wrong thing to call because: a) it will send EOF to the process and wait for EOF before exiting, and b) it will try to read from stdout/stderr, which you're already handling. With asyncio `communicate()` is generally much less needed because you *already* have the async tools which prevent the deadlock that `communicate()` is designed to prevent!

Comment: So ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(png_bytes) is that correct?

Comment: I've now noticed that `ffmpeg_process` is actually a coroutine. Still, there is no real issue, you just need to export the process created by `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec` to the global scope, e.g. by making `process` a global variable (or by switching to classes for proper state management). This is in no way specific to asyncio, just regular Python.

Comment: @user4815162342 I've updated the original post with the changes you suggested (see code at the bottom of the post, not the top). If those are correct you are most welcome to copy and paste that code into an answer and I will mark as correct after I have tested. One question - what specifically do I need to do to make ffmpeg_process global as you suggest - is it not already global?

Comment: Please refer to the last comment. Yes, `ffmpeg_process` is already global, but it doesn't contain the process instance (object returned by `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)`). **That** object is hidden in the `process` variable, which remains local to the function. You can make it global by using the `global` statement at the beginning of the function. Again, this is in no way specific to asyncio or to coroutines.

Comment: @user4815162342 OK I've updated the code above again - am I on track now?

Comment: It looks ok, but the idea is for you to *understand* the suggestion and continue on your own. If you have to ask if you are on track, then you must be missing something basic (like how Python global variables work) and I'm not really helping.

Comment: I think I have it from here - I greatly appreciate your kind help - you've gone above and beyond thank you.  It's my first program using asyncio and there's a bit of a learning curve to get my head around but with a bit of practice I'll come good.

Comment: Thanks, I've now posted a summary of the suggested changes as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code:

- `await reader.read(length)` should be `await reader.readexactly(length)` because the argument to [`StreamReader.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader.read) is the *maximum* number of bytes to read, and it can return fewer.
- `proc.communicate(png_bytes)` should be changed to `proc.stdin.write(png_bytes)`. The call to `communicate()` is incorrect here because you want to continue talking to the program, while `communicate()` waits for all the streams to close.
- The instance of process returned by `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)` must be made available to `socket_png_receiver`, e.g. by making the `process` variable global using `global process`. (It would be better to use a class and assign to `self.process`, but that is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Some potential issues:

- There is no need to decode `data` from bytes to string, `base64.b64decode` can accept bytes just fine.
- `spawn_ffmpeg()` doesn't appear to use its `listenport` parameter.

Comment: Indeed it works very well thanks/  Exactly what I wanted... spawns off video processing tasks nicely isolated from each other and the parent.